# Rotate image via Range Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, cropperjs

Hi guys how to make the image rotate via range slider?

I built the function so it can range between 0 and 360 and show the value range, it's working fine, but how to apply this to rotate the image?
    The crop image script documentation is [here](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs)

I updated the code with the crop script, please help to rotate the image and output to a div

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Cropper.js</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/cropper.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/0.8.1/cropper.css" />
  
  <style>
    .container {
      max-width: 640px;
      margin: 20px auto;
    }

    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Cropper with a range of aspect ratio</h1>
 
    <div>
      <img id="image" src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/images/picture.jpg" alt="Picture">
    </div>
 <button onclick="cropper.getCroppedCanvas()">Save</button>
  </div>

  <!-- <script src="dist/cropper.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/0.8.1/cropper.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var image = document.querySelector('#image');
      var minAspectRatio = 1.0;
      var maxAspectRatio = 1.0;
      var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
        ready: function () {
          var cropper = this.cropper;
          var containerData = cropper.getContainerData();
          var cropBoxData = cropper.getCropBoxData();
          var aspectRatio = cropBoxData.width / cropBoxData.height;
          var newCropBoxWidth;

          if (aspectRatio < minAspectRatio || aspectRatio > maxAspectRatio) {
            newCropBoxWidth = cropBoxData.height * ((minAspectRatio + maxAspectRatio) / 2);

            cropper.setCropBoxData({
              left: (containerData.width - newCropBoxWidth) / 2,
              width: newCropBoxWidth
            });
          }
        },
        cropmove: function () {
          var cropper = this.cropper;
          var cropBoxData = cropper.getCropBoxData();
          var aspectRatio = cropBoxData.width / cropBoxData.height;

          if (aspectRatio < minAspectRatio) {
            cropper.setCropBoxData({
              width: cropBoxData.height * minAspectRatio
            });
          } else if (aspectRatio > maxAspectRatio) {
            cropper.setCropBoxData({
              width: cropBoxData.height * maxAspectRatio
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  
  <script>
function updateTextInput(val) {
          document.getElementById('textInput').value=val; 
        }
        
</script>

<input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="360" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="">
  <!-- FULL DOCUMENTATION ON https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs -->

 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried the cropper's [`rotateTo`](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#rotatedegree) method?

Comment: Thanks, since I have the fuction to output the rotate degree, would be cool to test.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some javascript to set the rotation of the image when the slider value changes. Since you have jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  let slider = $('input[type=range]'),
      image = $('#image');

  slider.on('change mousemove', function(){
     image.css('transform', 'rotate(' + $(this).val() + 'deg)');
  });

});
```

*Side note: This type of event assignment - finding the element in javascript, rather than adding `onchange` attributes to the input - is much more flexible and maintainable.*

Here's an example: https://codepen.io/benjamin-hull/pen/ewxboE

**A couple of things to watch:**

I've added the 'mousemove' event listener as well as 'change', so the user gets real-time feedback as they move the slider. This might be a problem, as mousemove can produce 100's of events. You might need to look at 'debouncing' that event to limit it to a sensible value.

In my example, I've set the slider to min -180, max 180 and a default of 0. This allows the user to rotate left and right.

You probably want the rotation to scale the image as well, so it always fills the frame.

Comment: Cool, but when uploaded it will save as rotated picture?

Comment: Oh, hang on - I missed the crop image script link. This is really an integration question for https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs in that case - I was purely answering the 'rotate image with a slider' question. You should be able to pass the slider's value to the rotateTo option of the cropper, but your example isn't initializing the cropper yet, so you have some steps to do first. I would start with the cropper library's examples and work from there.

Comment: I will update the code with the cropper script, please check it again

Comment: Whoa - okay, I think it would be better to ask a separate question. The change here no longer makes sense with the title, and it means my answer no longer matches the question (and I think the original question would be helpful to others on its own, too!)

Comment: This thing is its an overlay its not part of the canvas how to make it part of the canvas for saving purposes? i try ctx.save(); but that stops things working!